# loop on element json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In local storage i have this syntax

Key

```
#setupHospitalCity:hospitalCity
```

Value

```
{"data":
[
    {"cityId":1,"city":"Abercorn"},
    {"cityId":2,"city":"ActonVale"},
    {"cityId":3,"city":"Adstock"},
    {"cityId":4,"city":"Aguanish"},
    {"cityId":5,"city":"Akulivik"}
],
"ttl":1443541460054}
```

With this code,

```
var values = localStorage.getItem("#setupHospitalCity:hospitalCity");
```

i get all the values

how to loop only to these block

```
{"cityId":1,"city":"Abercorn"},
{"cityId":2,"city":"ActonVale"},
{"cityId":3,"city":"Adstock"},
{"cityId":4,"city":"Aguanish"},
{"cityId":5,"city":"Akulivik"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {"data":
            [
                {"cityId":1,"city":"Abercorn"},
                {"cityId":2,"city":"ActonVale"},
                {"cityId":3,"city":"Adstock"},
                {"cityId":4,"city":"Aguanish"},
                {"cityId":5,"city":"Akulivik"}
            ],
            "ttl": 1443541460054
        }

        for (var x = 0; x < data["data"].length; x++) {
            alert(data["data"][x].city)
        }
```

Comment: data["data"] undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = values.data; // Returns a reference to the array.
for (var i = 0, ii = data.length; i < ii; ++i) { // Iterates over array.
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: i get an undefined with values.data

Answer (score 1):

You can loop it like any other array:

```
var values = localStorage.getItem("#setupHospitalCity:hospitalCity");   

var data = values.data;
for (var i = 0, len = values.data; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(values.data[i]); //values.data[i].cityId ...
}
```